# django model for subsite wagtail multisite

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I am creating a wagtail instance which includes actually 4 sites: a portal-site and three nearly identical subsites. The subsites contain in the footer a django-form, and within this django-form I want to include  a number of date-objects that are specific for the subsite.

To clarify the setup: there will be a subsite for kids-training, youth-training and adults-training. The form needs to include the next three training-dates (DateTime) for the target-group, and these dates need to be created by the site-owner.

I have not yet found a way to create a non-page model (django-model) that can be added to a subsite. Snippets seem not the way to go, and Site Settings does not seem to cover this usecase.

Any solution-suggestion would be welcome.